# Should the tag covalent-bond be split

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I think most people who use that tag mean discrete covalent molecules whereas it also includes network covalent structures and ionic compounds with a covalent nature. So make new tags- discrete covalent, network covalent and covalent nature? What do you think?

Comment: Are there existing questions that would fit with the `network-covalent` and `covalent-nature` tags?  If not, I would wait until we have an appropriate question before creating the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I would be in favor of creating a separate tag for network covalent bonding, since I think there could be a class of questions specifically relating to the nature of said bonding in crystalline solids which could be more particularly described by that tag than by some combination of the relevant existing tags (i.e., `covalent-compounds`, `crystal`, `crystalline-structure`). It would, for example, distinguish between questions pertaining to bulk properties of crystalline substances exhibiting network covalent bonding vs. questions that are more specifically concerned with the microscopic electronics of said bonding.